# Is there reference type information on stack in .Net

Tags: .net, memory

I'm diving in .Net memory structure and a little bit lost about where/why there is information about the reference (not the actual object) and what type it belongs to. Ok, it's a little bit confusing. Let me explain what I'm trying to understand by the example. I create the following memory object inside of a method:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
```

As the result I have an object on the heap with additional information about it saying that it's a memory stream object. At the same time I have a reference on the stack. This reference should be just a simple 32/64 bit word pointing to the object on the heap.

However, I can use only properties of the Stream class, right? So, is it just Visual Studio IntelliSense that parses information about what object reference I create and then limits to the Stream methods/properties or does CLR stores this information (that I declared my MemoryStream object as Stream) anywhere and checks it during the execution?

Comment: The CLR knows what the type of every object is at runtime.

Comment: But how does it know that the reference is to Stream? Where is this information stored?

Comment: @Intetics: The compiler knows that is a reference to `Stream` and thus knows which methods you can call and what code to emit. The reference "points" to the instance data of the stream but there is also some "hidden" information that provides information about the actual type (e.g. `MemoryStream`). This type information can be used for reflection and late binding using `dynamic` and also allows calls to virtual methods. But if no reflection, late binding or virtual methods are involved then the compiler simply emits a call to a specific method at a specific address in the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several gates your code have to pass successfully before it is allowed to run:

1. The compiler, it vets your code and will prohibit you from writing code that it knows won't run (at least in the context of this question)
2. The JITter and the verifier, it vets your compiled code when generating the machine code and will throw exceptions if the code is known to not be able to run (at least in the context of this question)

Both the compiler and the JITter knows the exact type of your variable and will thus ensure you cannot write code that tries to use stuff not available.

At IL level, the JITter will know which type of variable you have on the stack.

Once code reaches machine instructions, all bets are off. If you manage to sneak code past both the compiler and the JITter then anything can happen. This should only be possible if you encounter a bug in either or both.

Comment: Ok, so just to double check: the compiler, JITter and verifier all know about the Stream reference because it's either in the plain code (compiler) or in IL (JIT, verifier). However, during the actual machine code execution there is no mentioning about the Stream and only information about the MemoryStream in the heap. Correct?

Comment: You can use [Reflection.Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx) to build IL manually and bypass the compiler but the JITter and verifier will still (hopefully) prevent you from getting to execute obviously bad code. It isn't perfect however, so it *is* possible to get machine code that will behave badly.

Comment: Thanks Lasse. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a strongly typed language. This means the compiler generates code based on the type information:

```
Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
```

This will generate IL code that retrieves the `Stream.Length` property. This code is generated a compile time.

In this particular case the `Length` property is virtual (this is true for all members of the `Stream` class). This means that the actual call can have one level of indirection where the method table of the `MemoryStream` type is used to retrieve the `MemoryStream.Length` property. Sometimes the compiler is able to determine the that `Stream` instance is actually a `MemoryStream` and will then "directly" access the `MemoryStream.Length` property instead of going through the method table.

So when calling through reference the compiler will either create a direct call to the method or in the virtual case get the method table from the reference and then call the method in the method table.

If you "ignore" intellisense you can write code like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(stream.NonExistentProperty);
```

This will result in a compile error because the `Stream` class does not have a `NonExistentProperty` property. This happens at compile time and the code will never run.

However, there is a way to move this check from compile to run time by using `dynamic`:

```
dynamic stream = new MemoryStream();
Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
```

For this code the compiler generates code that at run time examines the type of the `stream` reference using reflection and then retrieves the `Length` property. If you write this code in Visual Studio you will discover that you loses intellisense for the `stream` variable.

The following code will also compile:

```
Console.WriteLine(stream.NonExistentProperty);
```

However, at run time you will get an error because there is no property named `NonExistentProperty` on the `MemoryStream` class.